# Configure kubernetes-dashboard to use metrics-server service instated of heapster.

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

I have installed kube v1.11, since heapster is depreciated I am using matrics-server. Kubectl top node command works.

Kubernetes dashboard looking for heapster service. What is the steps to configure dashboard to use materics server services

```
2018/08/09 21:13:43 Metric client health check failed: the server could not find the requested resource (get services heapster). Retrying in 30 seconds.
```

Thanks
SR

Answer (score 1):

This must be the week for asking that question; it seems that whatever is deploying heapster is omitting the `Service`, which one can fix [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51641057/how-to-get-the-resource-usage-of-a-pod-in-kubernetes/51645461#comment90363934_51645461) -- or the tl;dr is just: create the `Service` named `heapster` and point it at your heapster pods.

Answer (score 0):

As of today Kubernetes dashboard doesn't support matrics-server and it is expected to be released very soon with new release of kubernetes dashboard.
You can follow https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/issues/2986