# *4 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to kubernetes dashboard upstream

Tags: kubernetes

My Dashboard is not coming up. When I got the url I see this in the nginx logs
and on the browser I get **502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.13.8**

```
kubectl logs --follow -n kube-system deployment/nginx-ingress

2018/08/27 21:14:40 [error] 51#51: *4 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.125.16.80, server: osmsku---kubemaster01, request: "GET /kube-ui/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.77.5:9090/", host: "osmsku---kubemaster01"

10.125.16.80 - - [27/Aug/2018:21:14:40 +0000] "GET /kube-ui/ HTTP/1.1" 502 575 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

and on the dashboard logs I see this

```
2018/08/27 21:13:35 Creating in-cluster Heapster client

2018/08/27 21:13:35 Serving insecurely on HTTP port: 9090 
2018/08/27 21:13:38 Metric client health check failed: the server is currently unable to handle the request (get services heapster). Retrying in 30 seconds.  
2018/08/27 21:14:11 Metric client health check failed: the server is currently unable to handle the request (get services heapster). Retrying in 30 seconds.   
2018/08/27 21:14:44 Metric client health check failed: the server is currently unable to handle the request (get services heapster). Retrying in 30 seconds.
2018/08/27 21:15:17 Metric client health check failed: the server is currently unable to handle the request (get services heapster). Retrying in 30 seconds.
```

I tried deleting all the pods in the kube-system namespace. Deleted the dashboard/ heapster but nothing helped. Any ideas what is going on. or what to check.  Note, I have upgraded the cluster and everything came up fine after that. I rebooted the master node after upgrade and this is what happened

```
NAME                                           STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
osmsku---kubemaster01..local   Ready     master    140d      v1.11.2
osmsku---kubemaster02..local   Ready     <none>    140d      v1.11.2
osmsku---kubenode01..local     Ready     <none>    140d      v1.11.2
osmsku---kubenode02..local     Ready     <none>    140d      v1.11.2
```

Updated as per below comments:
77.5 is the docker interface ip

```
kubectl -n kube-system get -o wide svc
NAME                    TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE       SELECTOR
elasticsearch-logging   ClusterIP   10.110.162.147   <none>        9200/TCP         4h        k8s-app=elasticsearch-logging
heapster                ClusterIP   10.98.52.12      <none>        80/TCP           1h        k8s-app=heapster
kibana-logging          NodePort    10.99.101.8      <none>        5601:30275/TCP   4h        k8s-app=kibana-logging
kube-dns                ClusterIP   10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP    3h        k8s-app=kube-dns
kubernetes-dashboard    NodePort    10.99.131.186    <none>        80:32264/TCP     2h        k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard
monitoring-influxdb     ClusterIP   10.101.205.79    <none>        8086/TCP         1h        k8s-app=influxdb

kubectl get -o wide node
NAME                                           STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE                KERNEL-VERSION               CONTAINER-RUNTIME
osmsku--prod-kubemaster01..local   Ready     master    140d      v1.11.2   <none>        CentOS Linux 7 (Core)   3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64   docker://18.3.0
osmsku--prod-kubemaster02..local   Ready     <none>    140d      v1.11.2   <none>        CentOS Linux 7 (Core)   3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64   docker://18.3.0
osmsku--prod-kubenode01..local     Ready     <none>    140d      v1.11.2   <none>        CentOS Linux 7 (Core)   3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64   docker://18.3.0
osmsku--prod-kubenode02..local     Ready     <none>    140d      v1.11.2   <none>        CentOS Linux 7 (Core)   3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64   docker://18.3.0


   k get pods -n=kube-system
NAME                                                                   READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-78fcdf6894-qngz5                                               1/1       Running   2          2h
coredns-78fcdf6894-xdjcg                                               1/1       Running   1          2h
elasticsearch-logging-0                                                1/1       Running   2          2h
etcd-osmsku--prod-kubemaster01..local                      1/1       Running   15         2h
fluentd-es-v2.0.3-g77rm                                                1/1       Running   2          2h
fluentd-es-v2.0.3-x5bds                                                1/1       Running   3          2h
heapster-6d956577dc-d6l6k                                              1/1       Running   0          1h
kibana-logging-66fcf97dc8-57nd5                                        1/1       Running   1          2h
kube-apiserver-osmsku--prod-kubemaster01..local            1/1       Running   2          2h
kube-controller-manager-osmsku--prod-kubemaster01..local   1/1       Running   2          2h
kube-flannel-ds-4wdb7                                                  1/1       Running   3          2h
kube-flannel-ds-5g26z                                                  1/1       Running   2          2h
kube-flannel-ds-c9zss                                                  1/1       Running   3          2h
kube-flannel-ds-jbsfm                                                  1/1       Running   3          2h
kube-proxy-dzllb                                                       1/1       Running   1          2h
kube-proxy-gv2lf                                                       1/1       Running   2          2h
kube-proxy-gxd6b                                                       1/1       Running   2          2h
kube-proxy-hfwrv                                                       1/1       Running   2          2h
kube-scheduler-osmsku--prod-kubemaster01..local            1/1       Running   2          2h
kubernetes-dashboard-6bc9c6f7cb-f8g7s                                  1/1       Running   0          2h
monitoring-influxdb-cf9d95766-tkqhp                                    1/1       Running   0          1h
nginx-ingress-5659cc597-g9qg6                                          1/1       Running   0  

    2h
```

Comment: `get services heapster` is because of [the `heapster` `Service` failing to exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51645461)

Comment: Can you post the output of `kubectl -n kube-system get -o wide svc` as well as `kubectl get -o wide node` so we can see the CIDR of your Nodes and Services? It's hard to tell if 77.5 should be a Service IP, Node IP, or what

Comment: I get the same error (No route to host), albeit in another situation (trying to run a blockchain explorer). I read [this](https://github.com/dokku/dokku/issues/1796) and it seems that something like that can happen if you have run out of memory. Don't know if this is relevant in your case, just thought it might help someone reading this.